# Angular transcluded directive - can't access a model thats inside of it

Tags: angularjs, directive

This is my directive code:

```
'use strict';

demo.directive('myModal', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: '@',
        template: '<div ng-transclude><h4>Please enter value</h4></div>'
    }
});
```

Usage is as follows:

```
<!-- myModal directive -->
<div my-modal>
  <input type="text" ng-model="myTest" />
  <input type="button" ng-click="getMyTest()" value="Get Value" />
</div>
```

And my main controller, which wraps the whole application, includes this:

```
demo.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.getMyTest = function(){
    alert($scope.myTest);
  }

});
```

Any ideas why can't I access `myTest?`

**JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sZZEt/679/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the dot-notation:

```
demo.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.getMyTest = function(){
    alert($scope.data.myTest);
  }
});
```

and

```
<div my-modal>
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.myTest" />
  <input type="button" ng-click="getMyTest()" value="Get Value" />
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf6zskyo/)

Transclusion creates a child scope, that's why you should use the dot-notation for `ng-model`.

Comment: So I could theoretically do it in the directive controller itself, no? Is it the only work around?

Comment: No, as long as you use the transclusion.

Answer (score 1):

try this. add directive to model element.

```
<div>
    <input my-modal type="text" ng-model="myTest" />
    <input type="button" ng-click="getMyTest()" value="Get Value" />
</div>
```

Comment: It will work, but sadly it's not a practical solution for what my directive is meant for. Too much dependency. Thanks though